# How to create a custom PageRouteTransition with flip animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I want to replicate the Spotify flip transition in Flutter. [Video of transition](https://imgur.com/a/0SrxJtw).
So far I managed to do this: [isolated animation](https://dartpad.dev/?id=203e35825f966bbef7d81ed64ef91428) and ["working" transitions](https://dartpad.dev/?id=526e2dd8e76303ff75ba3d1bc47a6eee).

The video transition has its right edge always in touch with the screen, so I rotated from the centerRight and translated to negative X. The problem is that at 0.5 progress the animated widget is not centered neither the rotation is perpendicular to the screen.

```
class _RotationWidgetState extends State<RotationWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 6),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat();

  late final Animation<double> rotation =
      Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)).animate(controller);

  late final Animation<double> translation =
      Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: -1).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutSine)).animate(controller);

  double getTilt(double progress) => ((progress - 0.5).abs() - 0.5) * 0.002;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 500,
        width: 300,
      ),
      builder: (context, child) {
        var tilt = getTilt(controller.value);
        // if ((controller.value - 0.5).abs() < 0.001) controller.stop(); // stop animation at middle
        print(
            "Progress: ${controller.value} | Rotation: ${rad2deg(rotation.value)} | Translate: ${-300 * controller.value} ");
        return Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..rotateY(rotation.value)
            ..setEntry(3, 0, tilt)
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
            ..setTranslationRaw(300 * translation.value, 0, 0)
            ..setEntry(3, 3, 1), // dummy line to be able to comment above lines without comma errors
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This makes it imposible for me to craft the conditions for the transitionBuilder in my custom PageRouteBuilder. My best attempt:

```
PageRouteBuilder flipTransition(Widget screen) {
  const Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 1);

  return PageRouteBuilder(
    transitionDuration: duration,
    reverseTransitionDuration: duration,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => screen,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      final screenWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

      double getTilt(double progress) => ((progress - 0.5).abs() - 0.5) * 0.0015;

      final Animation<double> rotationEntry =
          Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)).animate(animation);
      final Animation<double> translationEntry =
          Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: -screenWidth).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutSine)).animate(animation);

      final Animation<double> rotationExit =
          Tween<double>(begin: pi, end: 0).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)).animate(secondaryAnimation);
      final Animation<double> translationExit =
          Tween<double>(begin: -screenWidth, end: 0).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutSine)).animate(
                secondaryAnimation,
              );

      return Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..setRotationY(animation.value >= 0.5 ? rotationEntry.value : 3 / 2 * pi)
          ..setTranslationRaw(translationEntry.value, 0, 0)
          ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
          ..setEntry(3, 0, getTilt(animation.value)),
        child: Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..setRotationY(secondaryAnimation.value < 0.5 ? rotationExit.value : pi / 2)
            ..setTranslationRaw(translationExit.value, 0, 0)
            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
            ..setEntry(3, 0, getTilt(secondaryAnimation.value)),
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

**Also: the secondaryAnimation is not triggered on the Home page, why is this? I want it to animate as any other pushed route.**

Comment: maybe because root page not in any PageRouteBuilder. give your rootpage a key('root'); on `transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {` , `print(child.key)`.